# How to display text in the same format as added in mysql text field using php echo

Tags: php, mysql, text, formatting, echo

I want to display a large amount of text using a php **echo** command. I have that data stored in mysql database table in a text field. What i want to achieve is that the data should be displayed in the same manner in which i store it in the text field.

for example:

**As entered in Mysql table by its Interface** One reason people lie is to achieve personal power.

Achieving personal power is helpful for someone who pretends to be more confident than he really is. For example, one of my friends threw a party at his house last month. He asked me to come to his party and bring a date.

Although this lie helped me at the time, since then it has made me look down on myself.

**Should be displayed exactly as the above rather than:** 
One reason people lie is to achieve personal power. 
Achieving personal power is helpful for someone who pretends to be more confident than he really is. For example, one of my friends threw a party at his house last month. He asked me to come to his party and bring a date.
 Although this lie helped me at the time, since then it has made me look down on myself.

Any ideas/tips on how this can be achieved?
I know that i can manually insert html tags between the text for formatting but i dont want to manually do so. Any way around?

Comment: You either need to parse the data when entering to the MySQL Database to add the HTML syntax for line breaks, paragraphs and other formatting. Or parse the raw results from the MySQL Database and add the HTML syntax as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nl2br($foo);` will automatically add a `<br>` tag wherever there is a linebreak in $foo. You can `echo nl2br($foo);`.

As an alternative, try the `<pre>` tag. `<pre><?php echo $foo; ?></pre>`. You many need more styling, but it will preserve whitespace like your linebreaks.

Comment: that was kindof what i was looking for. Though i knew about nl2br(); but i didn't thought of it for this purpose. Thanks anyways. For the time being this will solve my purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

- I'm using GWT TextArea textAreaWidget widget.
- Before insert the TextArea string to MySQL table I replace all line change and tab characters:

-new line

```
String toInsert=textAreaWidget.getText().replaceAll(Character.toString((char) 10), "\n\r"));
```

-tab

```
String toInsert=textAreaWidget.getText().replaceAll(Character.toString((char) 9), "\t"));
```

Example:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_textarea_widget.htm